# Crystal Reports: Adding new data table to results data set

Tags: crystal-reports

We are using SAP Crystal Reports with Visual Studio 2010.

To enhance our program with a new report, we have created a new data table and added it to our results data set. The problem however is that it is not possible to refresh the results data set in the Crystal Reports editor. As the screenshot shows, a window appears where we are supposed to enter connection credentials, and then we get an error message.

We have already had this problem several times before. Once, when we did essentially the same thing (add a new data table), it worked. So it seems to work sometimes, and sometimes it does not. But: How can we avoid this problem? It is really annoying and so far, I have been unable to add the data table which I have created today. This is a big problem.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Do you use an XSD file to define the schema? If Walter.Results.ResultsDataSet is a class, may you show the code of that class? (maybe it is a .net typed dataset, in this case you could post a print screen of the visual studio dataset designer, that would be fine too)

Comment: Walter.Results.ResultsDataSet is a class. It is declared as "`public class ResultsDataSet : DataSet`" and contains many data tables, which are derivatives of class DataTable, such as "`private Eingabe2DataTable eingabe2DataTable;`". The tables are filled with data this way:

`public void FillSolutionData(SolutionBase sol)
{
  lock (this)
  {
    projectDataTable.FillProjectData(sol);
    leitwertDataTable.FillSolutionData(sol.LeitwertMatrix);
    OnResultsDataSetChanged(new ResultsDataSetEventArgs(this));
  }
}`

Comment: Did you try to "log off" before refreshing? I know it is weird, since you did not really "log in" before. But try to right click on "database fields" in "field explorer" and click "log on or off server...". Then expand "current connections", select it's child and press the button "log off". Then close, right click again in "database fields" and choose "verify database" (yeah, i know it is not really a database, it is a class, but, you know, Crystal...)

Comment: When I click "Verify Database" I get a window where I am prompted to enter "connection information" such as file path and class name (as the screenshot shows). When I then click the OK button I get an error: "crdb_adoplus : Object reference not set to an instance of an object."